# Changed locale in R. Reset failes

Tags: r, macos

OS X 10.9.2 + R 3.0.2 and R 3.1.0

**I have set the locale in R** with

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "C")
```

because I wanted English weekday names in my plots. (LC_TIME locale was "de_DE.UTF-8")
This worked, but the change has become permanent. Restarting R gives:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
..
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"
```

**I tried to reset the locale with these commands:**

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "")
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "")
```

In both cases I got a warning:

```
..
OS reports request to set locale to "" cannot be honored
```

**I also did reinstall R** (in combination with an upgrade from R 3.0.2 to R 3.1.0
Nothing changed. May be the locale settings are stored in a dot-file, which is kept when upgrading, but I can't find where.

So if nobody knows a working reset command, an idea in which file the locale setting is stored may suffice.

Comment: Upon reinstallation, I'm pretty sure the locale is set by a call to your OS setup, so you really need to be more explicit about what you mean by "nothing changed".

Comment: My understanding was incomplete. I do see that the `?Sys.getlocale` page says "Note that the LANGUAGE environment variable has precedence over "LC_MESSAGES" in selecting the language for message translation on most R platforms. It doesn't say whether that applies to `weekdays()`

"

Comment: Have been unable to find out how to change the locale that affects weekday translation. Perhaps using the 'timeDate' package for your axis notation:  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/index.html

Comment: Before executing 'Sys.setlocale(..)' R started without warning and LC_TIME locale was 'de_DE.UTF-8'. Weekday names were german.
After executing 'Sys.setlocale(..)' Weekday names are english but R starts with '.. Setting LC_CTYPE failed ..'. The change was intended only for 4 plots but now it is permanent and I cannot undo it.

Comment: Try this: `Sys.setlocale(locale="de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8")`  I simple replace every instance of "en_US" with your locale-string in what my setup looks like.

Comment: `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "de_DE.UTF-8")` helps at lest temporary. R responds `[1] "de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/C"` and then behaves as I expect. For the first that is ok but in the long term I'd prefer a true and permanent reset.

Comment: Found a solution:`system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG de_De.UTF-8")` + restart makes the change and is permanent.

Comment: I will post the solution as answer tomorrow (In Germany it's after 2 o' clock in the night and I'm too tired)

Answer (score 2):

Enforcing the language setting with

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG de_DE.UTF-8")
```

or

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
```

plus restart fixed R on my computer. (I tested both settings.)

- R starts now without error
- The setting is permanent. I.e. I can quit and restart R and the setting "survives".
- The Sys.setlocale(..) command sets the locale temporarily
- The reset with Sys.setlocale(.., locale = "") works now!

Information on enforcing the language setting can be found in
`R -- Help -- R for Mac OS X FAQ -- 7 Internationalization of the R.app`:
If you use a non-standard setup .. you can override the auto-detection ...

Unclear is if it really was the Sys.setlocale() command that corrupted my system, or if it was something I did later. And unclear is if there is a way to reset the system to the original state. That would be in my eyes a more natural solution than enforcing the language setting.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has promised to post a more complete answer but it should be noted that it was in the R-for-MAC-FAQ

```
 7 Internationalization of the R.app
```

Comment: I was totally focused on some sort of reset. So I had to read this chapter 3 times to get the idea that enforcing the language setting might solve my problem.